# Curl returning null page

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to curl http://island-alpaca.selfip.com:10202/SnapShotJPEG?Resolution=640x480Quality=Standard this location and returning null page each time. my code is

```
  $image = 'http://island-alpaca.selfip.com:10202/SnapShotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Standard';

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image);

  $store = curl_exec ($ch);

  echo $store;
  curl_close ($ch);
```

Can anybody tell what i am missing?

Comment: why do you have space in url?

Comment: Sudhir gave you answer, you did not have returntransfer + did not change header of the page to jpg.

Answer (score 2):

try doing:

```
...
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image);
// Get binary data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);

$image = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// output to browser
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
```

**Edit**: try [urlencode()](http://www.php.net/urlencode)'ing the url as:

```
$image = 'http://island-alpaca.selfip.com:10202/SnapShotJPEG?Resolution='.urlencode('640x480&Quality=Standard');
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer !! without header and binary setting it will display all garbage data in the page. To the OP why on earth you want the image to get using CURL why not just use `<IMG>` tag and use the URL there ?

Comment: actually binarytransfer is not needed for php 5.1.3 on. From [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php): "From PHP 5.1.3, this option has no effect: the raw output will always be returned when CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is used."

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
```

so code will be:-

```
$image = 'http://island-alpaca.selfip.com:10202/SnapShotJPEG?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Standard';
 $ch = curl_init(); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
 $store = curl_exec ($ch); 
 curl_close ($ch);
 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
 echo $store;
```

Comment: have you any error try toenable  error_reporting(1);